# Hyphen use using.net Framework and HTML autocomplete feature

Tags: c#, accessibility, .net-4.8

I'm in the process of updating legacy .Net 4.8 framework forms to make them a little more accessible.
One of the recommendations was to make better use of the HTML attribute: autocomplete.

However for this feature to work you need to assign specific values to your form element
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

As I'm using c# .Net Framework 4.8 assigning an ID value containing a hyphen to a form control, will result in an error.

My understanding of how this works was that I need to name the ID value of the form control with the appropriate autocomplete attribute. In this case, email.
A basic example below. (I added the autocomplete="on" value to the textbox control separately)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" autocomplete="on"></asp:TextBox>
```

and this would be rendered as

```
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" autocomplete="on">
```

This is fine.

But what happens when I want to make use of another value like given-name (which contains an hypnen), well the .net complier pitches a fit.

The compiler gives me four errors all centred around this line in the designer.cs file. Specifically the -name; at the end

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox given-name;
```

How am I supposed make use of the autocomplete feature in .net framework when i can't add a hypen to the ID value?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `<asp:Textbox>` instead of `<input type="text" runat="server">`? (Using `HtmlControls` instead of `WebControls` tends to give you slightly more control over what gets rendered, including the ability to specify arbitrary attribute names and values).

Comment: _"But what happens when I want to make use of another value like given-name (which contains an hypnen), well the .net complier pitches a fit."_ - what is the **exact** error message that you saw? Was it from `csc` or from `aspnet_compiler` or something else?

Comment: No practical reason for the text box other than a I can see that fair few of the TB features are being used in code-behind. So a lot unpicking if it came to it.

Actual error messages. 
Error CS1003 Syntax error, ',' expected 
Error CS1002 ; expected 
Error CS1519 Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error CS1519 Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration

These all correspond to the -name; area i've highlighted in main question.